# Firebase Web - Reset password doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried to create a reset password page. But if I apply the action code it shows me, that the code is invalid. But it should be valid. So I guess the way I do it is wrong?! I also have a verify email page, where I also using applyActionCode, there it works fine. And yes I'm 100% sure that the oobCode must be correct.

```
console.log(this.$route.query.oobCode.toString())
firebase.auth().applyActionCode(this.$route.query.oobCode.toString()).then(
    (user) => {
        cosnole.log('user', user)
        user.updatePassword(this.password).then(
            function(user) {
                console.log('password updated')
            }).catch(
            function(err) {
                console.log(err.message)
            }
        )
    }).catch(
    function(err) {
        console.log(err.message)
    }
)
```

Comment: Can you show the error message you are getting in your question?

Comment: The action code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things to understand when resetting a users password using firebase auth using your example.

[**`applyActionCode`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#applyActionCode) returns [`firebase.Promise`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.Promise) containing `void`.

The user comes from `firebase.auth().currentUser` of a recently authenticated user.
[**`updatePassword`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html#updatePassword) also returns [`firebase.Promise`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.Promise) containing `void`

There is the option of using [**`confirmPasswordReset`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#confirmPasswordReset) that will combine the two above.

**Important:** The code must be the valid operation type (`PASSWORD_RESET`) returned from an email spawned by the [**`sendPasswordResetEmail`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#sendPasswordResetEmail) method

**The code would be something similiar to the following**

```
firebase.auth().applyActionCode(this.$route.query.oobCode.toString())
  .then( () => {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    user.updatePassword(this.password).then(
      () => {
        console.log('password updated')
      })
   .catch(
     error => {
       console.log(error.code, error.message)
     })        
  }
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.code, error.message)
  })
```

**or** [**`confirmPasswordReset`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#confirmPasswordReset)

```
firebase.auth().confirmPasswordReset(this.$route.query.oobCode.toString(), this.password)
  .then( () => {
    console.log('password updated')
  }
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.code, error.message)
  })
```

***NOTE:*** I have not confirmed your version of the code to update the password, but have used the `confirmPasswordReset`.

Comment: My code example was to correct the assumptions of your calls, but as I noted you may need to use `confirmPasswordReset` after a return of the code from the `sendPasswordResetEmail`

Comment: Thank you. The second way, confirmPasswordReset, is working.